# EditText hides screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textID"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="208dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="208dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_layout"
        android:hint="Input ID."
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textPassword"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="208dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="208dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_layout"
        android:hint="Input PassWord"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I created a simple `EditText`. When I touch the `EditText` to type, the `EditText` field hides the screen.

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

This didn't solve the problem of the `EditText` field taking up the entire screen.

This app automatically switches to landscape mode when launched. Is this the problem?

This is a reference photo:

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"....try it...

Comment: I used it, but it stays the same as the photo.
I can't solve the problem.
Is there a way to make the EditText window appear and only the keyboard is visible?

Comment: make height wrap_content and android:maxLines="1"

Comment: Only the size of the EditText input field is reduced.
The underlying issue of covering the entire screen when touched has not been resolved.

Comment: Can you give portrait mode screen shot?

Comment: can you paste full xml?

Comment: Sorry,
I couldn't check the comments because I didn't access the site.
I solved the above problem.           android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"    
I solved it using the code above.
I added it inside EditText </> in the .xml file.